# Base64-like encrypted string

Tags: android, encryption, base64

I have a "Base64?" encoded string that returns bad characters.

```
32CoKBgacngtXPLkFegJVCjx0N8=
```

In theory it may have numbers and also some symbols.

B.R.
 Tux

EDIT:

Solved, it was a unprotected SHA-1, here is the method:
   1-. With adb installed an the device plugged execute this on a command line: `adb shell cat /data/data/com.domobile.applock/shared_prefs/com.domobile.applock_preferences.xml`
   2-. In the XML file search for `1234abcd==` and copy the Base64 code.
   3-. Go to http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php and paste the Base64.
   4-. Click on Convert an copy resultant hexadecimal code.
   5-. Go to http://www.string-functions.com/case.aspx and convert all to lowercase.
   6-. Copy the lowercase code and paste in a text editor.
   7-. As said on http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/android-forensics-cracking-the-pattern-lock-protection/ download the rainbow table -> http://www.mediafire.com/download/qs0sq5h8e2ly8jg/SHA1-android-pattern.rar 
   8-. Extract it with the password `www.marw0rm.com` and open with `sqlitebrowser` or a similar app
   9-. Execute this query in the database: `select * from RainbowTable where hash = "(here your hash that we paste on text editor)"`
   10-. The result is the decrypted pattern as this `[a,b,c,d,e...]` trace it in the screen according to this picture http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/081913_1401_AndroidFore3.png

Comment: what you exectly want??

Comment: Decrypt this "Base64-like" text. or debug the android app that generates it to see how is generated.

Comment: Is it a **password** you are **trying to crack**? Anyway, `"Base64-like"` means **`NOTHING`**. IS or ISN'T Base64. You can't go "by guess".

Comment: Is your question "how do I decode a base64 encoded string"? Or is it "how do I debug an Android application"? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: No, is a lock pattern... The generator app is AppLock and I have the password... is the tablet of a friend, but he said me "The AppLock password is XXXX, I challenge you to crack the pattern" and is a hard work. The config file is /data/data/com.domobile.applock/shared_prefs/com.domobile.applock_preferences.xml

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Mainly  "how do I decode a (seens obfuscated base64 or something like) encoded string"

Comment: What does "crack the pattern" mean?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Get the pattern sequence (ex: 1,2,3,6,5,4,7,8,9) and draw in a paper his pattern. A pattern like this http://playingwithmodels.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/unlock_pattern.png

Comment: The xml entry is: <string name="image_lock_pattern">32CoKBgacngtXPLkFegJVCjx0N8=</string>

Comment: The Base64 decodes to 20 bytes of data. Without knowing the exact details, I believe it is safe to assume it is actually a *hash* of the pattern, maybe SHA1, possibly keyed with a secret embedded inside the code. You'll have a hard time retrieving the pattern.

Comment: @JoanCharmant: But... ¿How? ¿Can I make a BruteForce script that probes codes? Here is the XML: http://pastebin.com/Pg4LBWTz. P. D.: If I change the password the code doesn't changes, conclusion: password isn't the salt

Comment: Well, how can you prove us you are doing this for educational purposes and not to hack someone else account ?

Comment: ¿Account? ¿with a pattern? ¿with only a few games locked into Applock? ¿A pactically new tablet (lets say unused)?. Anyway is a delicate topic... ¿How can prove it? say you the method. Regarding to the Base64 in a on-line converter http://www.businessinfo.co.uk/labs/hackvertor/hackvertor.php testing and touching I found an algorythm with that response: String identified as:partial key or sub cipher:GW0KBgacngtXPLkFegJVCjx0N8=

Comment: Now my friend will stay amazed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was a unprotected SHA-1, here is the method:
   1-. With adb installed an the device plugged execute this on a command line: `adb shell cat /data/data/com.domobile.applock/shared_prefs/com.domobile.applock_preferences.xml`
   2-. In the XML file search for `1234abcd==` and copy the Base64 code.
   3-. Go to http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php and paste the Base64.
   4-. Click on Convert an copy resultant hexadecimal code.
   5-. Go to http://www.string-functions.com/case.aspx and convert all to lowercase.
   6-. Copy the lowercase code and paste in a text editor.
   7-. As said on http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/android-forensics-cracking-the-pattern-lock-protection/ download the rainbow table -> http://www.mediafire.com/download/qs0sq5h8e2ly8jg/SHA1-android-pattern.rar 
   8-. Extract it with the password `www.marw0rm.com` and open with `sqlitebrowser` or a similar app
   9-. Execute this query in the database: `select * from RainbowTable where hash = "(here your hash that we paste on text editor)"`
   10-. The result is the decrypted pattern as this `[a,b,c,d,e...]` trace it in the screen according to this picture http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/081913_1401_AndroidFore3.png